# EclipseRT/Virgo not appearing in Eclipse Server Adapter list

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, eclipse-virgo

I'm trying to get up and running with Virgo, and I'm following along with what appears to be an [excellent tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-2.1.0.M02-incubation/docs/virgo-programmer-guide/htmlsingle/virgo-programmer-guide.html#tooling-running), but I'm at [section 7.2](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-2.1.0.M02-incubation/docs/virgo-programmer-guide/htmlsingle/virgo-programmer-guide.html#tooling-running) and I just can't figure out why EclipseRT / Virgo doesn't appear in my list of options.

So far I've been using SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) as the guide recommended and have installed all the Spring dm Server Tools and Developer Resources bundles.

Has anyone else run into this issue or have a solution to getting the EclipseRT/Virgo server adapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Virgo 2.1.0.RELEASE](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/download/) and STS 2.5.0.RELEASE are both now out. The problems you had with the docs should be resolved. The documentation has also been updated to show the latest information as well.

Comment: I finally circled back and picked up the latest version of Virgo, documentation and product are substantially more mature. At the time I didn't realize things were in such massive transaction...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the STS 2.6.0 upgrade removes this server adapter! Refer to the STS JIRA entry [STS-1690](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-1690) for details on this removal. You can simply go to the Dashboard > Extensions tab and select "dm Server Support Extension" to put it back.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, have a look at this [eclipse forum for virgo](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=173207&start=0&S=6ed5b54b6ec2d61360953def403f8e89)

Seems like you have to get used to playing with the update sites until you find the right one. I imagine that by the time anyone reads this the url will probably have morphed every so slightly yet again. Sigh. Comes of playing with tech while they're still actively releasing.

Answer (score 0):

I've been just playing around with Virgo 2.1.1 and Eclipse STS 2.7.1.
Indeed there is no Virgo server adapter, but you can install it from this update site:
 http://download.eclipse.org/virgo/milestone/IDE

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is searching for more recant information, one need to install  DM Server Tooling from http://dist.springsource.com/release/DMS-TOOLS/update to get Virgo in the server add dialog.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version of STS (3.1.0), I tried many ways suggested, and find only the Eclipse Virgo/Tooling wiki works.
(http://wiki.eclipse.org/Virgo/Tooling#Install_Eclipse)

It adds the EclipseRT/Virgo adapter in STS 3.1.0.